# Laravel two similar routes, second route not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.8, I have two routes:

```
Route::get('/exam-info/{id}', 'ExamController@mainExamInfo')->name('main_exam_info');

Route::get('/exam/{id}', 'ExamController@startMainExam')->name('start_main_exam');
```

When I go to the second route it gives me "page not found" error! Why?

**Update:**

In ExamController my `startMainExam` function is:

```
public function startMainExam($exam_id){
        dd("sss");
        // other stuff
}
```

**But**  when I change the second route to:

```
Route::get('/exaxxxx/{id}', 'ExamController@startMainExam')->name('start_main_exam');
```

It works!!

Comment: Could you add the code of your ExamController class?

Comment: could you also provide the whole route script, and write the exact url you're requesting

Comment: @DeesOomens see  my update

Comment: That's weird, maybe you have cached your routes, do you have a `bootstrap/cache/routes.php` file? Is your route present if you execute `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @Demonyowh I don't have any routes similar to exam, there are lots of routes lie `activate`,`dashboard`...,  The url: `http://localhost:8000/exam/3`  -   See updated question

Comment: Also check how many results do you get by executing: `php artisan route:list | grep exam/{id}`

Comment: @namelivia, three results:  `activate-exam`, `exam-info/{id}`, `exam/{id}`

Comment: i think there is another route that is listening for the same method and it does not work because of the (-) character https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters try changing it to exam_info and see if it works

Comment: Check and verify by running "php artisan route:list"

Answer (score 0):

Do you defined resource route on `ExamContorller`. Something similar like below on your route.php

```
Route::resource('exam', 'ExamController');
```

If it present, please change the second route name to something else like `/exam-id/{id}`

Comment: No, I do not have  route ::resource

Comment: Then, can you please verify the route name your are calling is correct or try to change the name to something else like /exam-id/{id} and see its working